# What is Ember metal?

Tags: ember.js

What is Ember metal? Can I use it?

I tried getting ember metal from `Ember.metal` and `Ember.Metal` but they were not defined.

I saw it because I was reading ember core code, and I see it's used a couple of times.
[image: _emberMetal]

Comment: what and why do you want to use about it?

Comment: @Lux I want to learn what it does, input/output. and if it can be used from the outside.

Comment: its just some parts of ember. For example [`get` comes directly from metal](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/functions/@ember%2Fobject/get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ember-metal](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/modules/ember-metal) is the namespace for all core/base ember methods - basically, it's the dirty guts of the system.

It's probably a reference to "stripping down to the metal", which is removing the nice, flashy, and appealing parts so you have a solid base to build on.

Comment: how, do I use it's methods? From the ember object is it possible?

Comment: You wouldn't want to use it directly.    It's a private class, meaning you shouldn't, and that it's not guarenteed to work the same way between versions.  
If it's doing something you want to use, work your way up the stack and track down the public version of it.

Comment: @Rainb As a general rule, if you see errors coming from ember-metal, something's gone slightly (or very) wrong in your application code and it's just blowing up in lower level Ember code far from the actual problem.